# Finding first occurence of multiples value in every group sort by date in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a table with every operations that appends before an event group by another value.

There is only 3 operations: R, E, P

```
+ ----------+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| Rollcycle | Blocking | Operation | Order                  |
+ ----------+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| 1         | 3        | R         | 4                      |
| 1         | 3        | P         | 3                      |
| 1         | 3        | E         | 2                      |
| 1         | 3        | R         | 1                      |
| 1         | 2        | P         | 3                      |
| 1         | 2        | E         | 2                      |
| 1         | 2        | R         | 1                      |
| 1         | 1        | R         | 1                      |
| 2         | 1        | E         | 2                      |
| 2         | 1        | R         | 1                      |
+ ----------+----------+-----------+------------------------+
```

I want to know which operations occurs before every blocking group by Rollcycle.
I need to do this in access SQL.

Output

```
+ ----------+----------+---+---+---+
| Rollcycle | Blocking | R | E | P |
+ ----------+----------+---+---+---+
| 1         | 1        | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1         | 2        | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1         | 3        | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2         | 1        | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+ ----------+----------+---+---+---+
```

I could not find anything similar. It's maybe too specific.

Please help :)

EDIT: back to original table

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can filter on records where `order` is greater or equal than `blocking`, and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    rollcycle,
    blocking,
    max(iif(operation = 'R', 1, 0)) R,
    max(iif(operation = 'E', 1, 0)) E,
    max(iif(operation = 'P', 1, 0)) P
from mytable 
where order >= blocking
group by rollcycle, blocking
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do that since Order is a date and not a number like blocking... I will edit my post so it's more clear.

Comment: @Bunny: well, that's a different question now... It is not a good practice to substantially edit the question after answers were posted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this... I will post a new question next time.

Comment: I went back to the original table and post a new question with the edit

Comment: I tried modify my query to match this question. But your awnser give only give me   the last operation (max) and I need all of them.